# Call a procedure instead of opening a new instance

Tags: c#

I believe what I need is reflection, but after looking into it I'm not sure how I'm supposed to make it work.

I'm trying to run a second instance of the application that should tell the main instance to execute a procedure, and this code must run from the first instance. I've been able to identify if an instance is already running by using a mutex.

```
if (Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true) == false)
{
     //program already has an instance running
     //How do I call a method on the first (already running) instance
}
```

What I'd like it to do is execute a procedure from the first (already running) instance.

Comment: @Servy So I would need to use WCF? I thought since it's the same executable and that I maintain the code that there would be a different way.

Comment: This goes into IPC. But actually there is a class for this. It is somewhat hidden in the VB.Net specific DLL's, but it should still be useable.http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx

Comment: @MichaelZ. There are any number of ways to communicate between two processes.  WCF is one of them.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, you're right. I suppose it could even be as easy as using a file. Thanks for the info.

Comment: My app is a hotkey app and my current setup simply has the new instance send a hotkey that the first instance will pickup and handle. It's a hotkey that nobody would ever choose since it uses all four modifier keys. I think I'll just keep it the way it is. EDIT: it's not hotkeys persay, since I'm using a keyboard  hook as opposed to the Win32 call `RegisterHotkey`